# Simple Relation between 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a problem here.

I cannot add this to my db because one table is dependent of another and vice-versa.

So I get

> Cannot add foreign key constraint

on the first create table that I put

How can I add this 2 tables if they both have constraints??

```
    -- User Roles
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_roles` (
  `user_role_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `role` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_role_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uni_username_role` (`role`,`username`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ix_auth_username` (`username`,`role`),
  KEY `fk_username_idx` (`username`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_username` FOREIGN KEY (`username`) REFERENCES `users` (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- Users
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `username` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hashedPassword` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `enabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `image` mediumblob,
  `team` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `userRole` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`username`),
  KEY `fkteam_idx` (`team`),
  KEY `fkrole_idx` (`userRole`),
  CONSTRAINT `fkrole` FOREIGN KEY (`userRole`) REFERENCES `user_roles` (`user_role_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fkteam` FOREIGN KEY (`team`) REFERENCES `team` (`idteam`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: You probably should not have `userRole` in `users`.  You have another table for the roles.

Comment: I actually think that I should not have username in User_Roles. Just the id and role

Comment: I think userRole should be NOT NULL in users also

Comment: but i have no idea what I am doing so I can be wrong

Comment: You should really make sure that you need both foreign keys in your schema, this is usually a bad design as the relationship is in one way (a user has a role - foreign key on User, a user has many roles - 3rd table with both foreign keys if roles can be given to many users also). If this 1 to 1 schema is what you need, then create the tables first and add the constraints after the creation.

Comment: I would user a third table to link users to roles.  Most applications have users that can have multiple roles, and the reverse is implied.  So remove both constraints, and create a `Users_have_roles` table.  That table will have the foreing key constraints linking it to the `Users` and `Roles` tables.

Comment: I don't think you would need a username column in user_roles table. Because in the future you may have same role assigned to multiple users. Best way is to enter role_id in users table alone

Comment: In your problem what is the relation between users and roles? `ManyToMany` ot `OneToMany` ? it means each user has only one role or it can has multiple roles ?

Comment: Try using  ON DELETE CASCADE and ON UPDATE CASCADE

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you'll need to use **deferrable constraint checks**, but unfortunately MySQL does not implement this *standard* SQL feature.

As far as I know, only Oracle and PostgreSQL support this feature (deferrable constraints). These constraints **are checked at the end of the transaction**, and not on every single row insertion. That would solve your problem.

Therefore, you have two options:

- Switch to Oracle or PostgreSQL (unlikely, I guess) or,
- Change your table definition to allow one of the foreign key constraints to accept null values.

In the second case, you would:

- Insert in the table that allow null in the FK, getting the generated ID.
- Insert in the other table using the ID. Then, get the second generated ID.
- Update the null in first table using the second ID.
- Commit.

That's it.